# JavaScript function from external JS file will not launch

Tags: javascript

I have the following test.html file and from it I'm trying to call `sayHello()` from the `myjslib.js` file. `sayHello` simply prints "Hello!" to the console but nothing is printing. How do I call `sayHello` from the `test.html` file? This question may seem like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313710/using-html-script-tags-to-code-while-they-have-a-source) question. But, that question is addressing the use of script code inside a script tag that has a src attribute. I now have the function call in a separate script tag yet they still does not launch.

HTML body

```
<body>
    <script src="myjslib.js"></script>
    <script>
        sayHello();
    </script>
</body>
```

These are the functions in the JavaScript file

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello!");
}

function sayGoodbye() {
    console.log("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the console? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code like this:

```
<script src="myjslib.js"></script>
<script>        
  sayHello();
</script>
```

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) about `src` attribute

Comment: Thanks for responding Flying but after refactoring I now get "Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined"

Comment: I edited the above to reflect what I now have after refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Flying. I probably didn't save my changes but now it works as you suggested.